# How to Remove Diaglog Title Icon in Prism

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I am using prism dialog to show a dialog popup in MVVM.

```
_iDialogService.ShowDialog("View", new DialogParameters(""), CallBackResult=>
            {
              var test = CallBackResult;
            });
```

[image: Pop up Dialog]
Doe anyone know how to remove popup title image

Answer (score 0):

What you are circling comes from the DialogWindow not the Dialog View. As such you need to provide a custom Dialog Window that is configured the way you want.

Note you can see the default [DialogWindow](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/src/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Services/Dialogs/DialogWindow.xaml) that ships as part of Prism on GitHub.

You can create your own dialog window by either inheriting from Dialog Window and setting the properties that you want. Alternatively you may want to just inherit from Window and implement IDialogWindow.

```cs
public class MyDialogWindow : DialogWindow
{
}

public class MyOtherDialogWindow : Window, IDialogWindow
{
}
```

In your Bootstrapper or PrismApplication you'll want to be sure to register your Window along with your Dialogs:

```cs
containerRegistry.RegisterDialog<MyDialog>();
containerRegistry.RegisterDialogWindow<MyDialogWindow>();
```

Finally be sure to add the name of your dialog when you use the DialogService

```cs
dialogService.ShowDialog("MyDialog", parameters, onDialogClosed, "MyDialogWindow");
```

Comment: I am using Prism 6, after i implement it and It throw error 'A dialog's content must be a FrameworkElement' i may miss something? The implementation is below.

Comment: ```register:
 containerRegistry.RegisterDialogWindow<MyDialogView>();```

Comment: ```call:
 _iDialogService.ShowDialog("MyDialogView", new DialogParameters(""), result =>
            {
                SlideDescription = _viewModelShareData.SlideDescription;
            }); ```

Comment: ```view:
 public class MyDialogViewModel : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged, IDialogWindow```

Comment: ```viewmodel:
  public class MyDialogViewModel : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged, IDialogAware```

Comment: you should update to Prism 7.2... Prism 6 is several years old and not supported

Comment: i have to use prism 6 for project reason

Comment: @DanSiegel, I'm trying to do this with Prism 8. I've created MessageBoxWindow that implements IDialogWindow, as well as registered MessageBoxWindow and MessageBoxView. When I run it, I get "Unable to resolve resolution root Prism.Services.Dialogs.IDialogWindow {ServiceKey="MessageBoxWindow"} from container without scope". Not sure what I may have done wrong.

Comment: Fixed it with "containerRegistry.RegisterDialogWindow<MessageBoxWindow>(nameof(MessageBoxWindow));"